# Help to identify components, a SOT23 marked RO and SOD123 marked with 14

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, identification

[image]

I need help to identify a SOT23 marked RO and SOD123 marked with 14. The board is Ender3 s1 pro motherboard. Cathode side of the diode comes from directly +24 V. Anode side is connected to the RO marked component and the bottom side of the RO component connected directly to the ground. Upper pin of the RO component connected to the chip below which is HCT245. These two R0 component drives the fan voltages of the Ender3 s1 pro.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly CHT848BWPT-Q The Datasheet below matches the packages and markings.

https://www.datasheetq.com/datasheet-download/942757/1/CHENMKO/CHT848BWPT

Comment: Could the component marked with ro be the n channel mosfet? because 24v needs to flow from the ground to the anode end of the diode. So the gate is the pin coming from the chip. 0.1a 40v npn transistor didnt work

Comment: 100mA sounds low for a fan output with a 1A clamp diode. But stranger things have happened. I think the pictured device is SOT-23, not 323. Doesn't seem to be any good candidates in the standard lists.

Comment: i used pnp 200ma 40v transistor and it working now but always full speed. i cannot control the fan speeds anymore

Answer (score 1):

”14” is probably SS14 diode. 40 V, 1 A Schottky in SMA capsule.

Datasheet: [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88746/ss12.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The component marked "RO" can be the NPN Transistor KTC3879. Here is a link to the datasheet. [Link to datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1137270/HOTTECH/KTC3879/1)

You can find the device marking here.
[image]
This tells your device has a DC current gain of 70-140.